# Codeigniter-Problem while using yearweek('datefield') in where class

Tags: php, codeigniter

Today I met the problem in CodeIgniter framework when I was trying to filter using date field with `yearweek()`. Here is my query in normal without CodeIgniter style definition

```
SELECT b.name as branch,str_to_date(concat(yearweek(gp.createddate), 'sunday'), '%X%V %W') as week,sum(case when amount>0 then qty else 0 end) as purchase_quantity,sum(case when amount>0 then gp.amount else 0 end) as purchase_amount,sum(case when amount<0 then qty else 0 end) as return_quantity,sum(case when amount<0 then gp.amount else 0 end) as return_amount FROM `group_purchase` gp LEFT JOIN `branch` b ON gp.branchid=b.id WHERE yearweek(gp.createddate)=yearweek('2018-12-24')  GROUP BY gp.branchid,yearweek(gp.createddate) ORDER BY yearweek(gp.createddate) DESC
```

That was worked fine and result was produced accurately.i was use `yearweek()` for grouping data in week wise.when i was implementing this query into codeigniter all the things was worked fine except `yearweek()`.I attached my codeigniter model for above query below

```
function getPurchasereport($limit,$offset,$order_column,$order_type,$parameters)
{

    $this->db->select("b.name as branchname,str_to_date(concat(yearweek(gp.createddate), 'sunday'), '%X%V %W') as week,sum(case when amount>0 then qty else 0 end) as purchase_quantity,sum(case when amount>0 then gp.amount else 0 end) as purchase_amount,sum(case when amount<0 then qty else 0 end) as return_quantity,sum(case when amount<0 then gp.amount else 0 end) as return_amount");
     if($parameters['branch']!=NULL){
       $this->db->like('gp.branchid',$parameters['branch']);
    }
    if($parameters['cdatefrom']!=NULL){
       $this->db->where('yearweek(gp.createddate)',yearweek("$parameters['cdatefrom'])");
    }
    $this->db->group_by(array("gp.branchid", "yearweek(gp.createddate)"));
    if(empty($order_column) || empty($order_type)){
        $this->db->order_by('yearweek(gp.createddate)','asc');
    }else{
        $this->db->order_by($order_column,$order_type);
    }
    if($limit!=0){
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    }
    $this->db->join('branch b','gp.branchid=b.id ','left');
    $query = $this->db->get('group_purchase gp');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result_array();
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

it produced error like below 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq7kt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have is because of this line

```
if($parameters['cdatefrom']!=NULL){
       $this->db->where('yearweek(gp.createddate)',yearweek("$parameters['cdatefrom'])");
    }
```

the function `yearweek` is not valid PHP function, therefore you cannot use it that way.
you need to replace it with the below:

```
if($parameters['cdatefrom']!=NULL){
       $this->db->where('yearweek(gp.createddate)',date('YW',strtotime($parameters['cdatefrom'])));
    }
```

Comment: it was doesn't filter anything and doesn't show any error

Comment: it doesn't return any result then not show any error also

Comment: if it doesn't show any error, it means it is fixed, now for not returning any result, you can check the output of the function, or print the query and check it, then post what it says so I can help.

Comment: Thanx, it was worked fine now there is a small bug in coding that was cleared.

Comment: glad it worked out for you, if anything comes up, please do ask and I'll do my best to help

Comment: definitely i will do